# Finding inflection points and concavity for given function

Tags: functions, curvature

I have to explore function $\frac{2x-4}{1+x^2}$
It contains finding definition area of function, finding roots etc. One of the points is to find inflection points and concavity of function. I cannot find it.

I have found out first and second derivative of function.
From first derivative I find out two points where f(x)'=0.
$x1=(2+\sqrt{5})$ and $x2=(2-\sqrt{5})$

Then I have tried to find second derivative and it is: $\frac{4x^3-24x^2-12x+8}{(x^2+1)^3}$. 
I beleive I have to solve f(x)''=0 to find something about functions concavity, but I cannod do it.

Comment: Can't you solve cubic equations using Cardano ? It is not funny for your case, I am afraid ! By the way, $f''(x)$ is fine.

Comment: In any case, I cannot find the roots. I just tried to use the software, it gives three points -0.806;0.387;6.419. What are the next steps to find if convex and concave intervals?

Comment: $f''(x)$ is cubic with a positive leading coefficient. So, it starts negative (up to $-0.806$), positive (from $-0.806$ to $0.387$), negative (from $0.387$ to $6.419$) and postive above $6.419$. Is this OK for you ?